# How to create the equation recurrence relationship

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$a_{n+1}= 2^{n}− a_{n}= $

$a_{n+1}=2( a_{n} + a_{n−1} ) − a_{n}$      I don't understand that part

$a_{n+1} =a_n+2a_{n−1}$.

that makes $x^2 -x -2$

How can I do the same thing with this exercise :
$a_{n+1}=6a_{n} + 2^{n}$

I am trying to do the same thing

as a result I have $a_{n+1} = 2( 6a_{n} + a_{n+a} )$

$a_{n+1}=6a_{n} + 2a_{n+1}$ I am not sure about that..
so $x^2-6x-2$

Your opinion about this?

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title.

Comment: The second line should have $a_{n-1}$ where you have $a_{n-a}$

Comment: @WW1 ok i edited

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to find an explicit formula for $a_n$? If so, start by using the recurrence relation to find the first few terms, and you should be able to identify a pattern (you would need to be given the value of $a_1$). i.e. $a_2 = 2^1 - a_1, a_3 = 2^2 - a_2 = 2^2 - 2^1 + a_1$ etc

Comment: I am using linear method to do this

Comment: Your first sentence is completely obscure. Please rework it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_{n+1}=6a_n+2^n \implies a_n=6a_{n-1}+2^{n-1}\implies2a_n=12a_{n-1}+2^n$

So $8a_n-12a_{n-1}=6a_n+2^n$ and we get:

$a_{n+1}=8a_n-12a_{n-1}$

Then as before $x^2-8x+12=0=(x-2)(x-6)$.

$a_n=c_12^n+c_26^n$

$c_12^{n+1}+c_26^{n+1}=6(c_12^n+c_26^n)+2^n$

$2c_1+6c_2=6c_1+6c_2+1\implies c_1=\frac{-1}{4}$

$c_2$ cannot be determined without more information.

$a_n=2^n(c_1+c_23^n)$

$a_0=c_2-1/4\implies c_2=a_0+\frac{1}{4}$

I think that does it.

Comment: I got you and you are detailed enough,my issue with your answer is your first sentence I don't really understand  after your first => the second line and after this is ok

Comment: the recurrence must be true for any $n$, so it will still be true if your replace $n$ with $n-1$

Comment: So if I understand good, he replace on the first => $a_{n}$=6$a_{n-1}$+$2^{n−1}$ the n with n-1 ok.Got that ,after the second =>  what he does?

Comment: Multiply by 2 to get a new equation. Then notice that if you add $6a_n$ to both sides, you get $6a_n+2^n$ as part of the equation. Swap in $a_{n+1}$ and rearrange to get the next expression.

Comment: @WW1 It seems like he multiple with 2, so the $a_n$ will be 2$a_{n}$ so next after the = we have 6$a_{n-1}$ also it seems like multiple with 2 and it becomes 12$a_{n-1}$ but what about $2^{n}$ ??

Comment: @TurlocTheRed thank you a lot

Comment: $2(a_n=6a_{n-1}+2^{n-1} )\iff 2a_n=2\cdot 6a_{n-1}+2\cdot 2^{n-1}=12a_{n-1}+2^n$

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a general method, notice that if :
$$a_{n + 1} = x a_n + y 2^n$$
then dividing by $2^{n + 1}$ :
$$\dfrac{a_{n + 1}}{2^{n + 1}} = \dfrac{x a_n + y 2^n}{2^{n + 1}} = \dfrac{x}{2} \dfrac{a_n}{2^n} + \dfrac{y}{2} \dfrac{2^n}{2^n} = 
\dfrac{x}{2} \dfrac{a_n}{2^n} + \dfrac{y}{2}$$
Consider the sequence :
$$b_n = \dfrac{a_n}{2^n}$$
so we have :
$$b_{n + 1} = \dfrac{x}{2} b_n + \dfrac{y}{2}$$
It's easy to study this kind of sequences (arithmetico-geometric sequences). First look for $c$ such that :
$$c = \dfrac{x}{2} c + \dfrac{y}{2}$$
and the sequence :
$$c_n = b_n - c$$
will be geometric.

Comment: sorry ,but the second part is not divided by $2^{n+1}$ it is only divided by 2 or $2^{n}$ same with y/2 it should have been $y/$2^{n+1}$

Comment: $y$ has already $2^n$ as factor.

Comment: I edited it to make it clear.

Comment: I see but still I don't get HOW to do this like x^2 +2x-2 something like that..

Comment: It's just a technic to have recurrence of first order only.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to eliminate the RHS $2^n$. You can write

$$a_{n+1}=6a_n+2^n\implies 2^{n-1}=a_n-6a_{n-1}$$ and

$$a_{n+1}=6a_n+2(a_n-6a_{n-1}).$$

The characteristic equation is

$$x^2-8x+12=0.$$

Comment: can you be more detailed in first sentence..

Answer (score 0):

$$2^n = a_{n+1}-6a_n $$
and so
$$2^{n-1} = a_n-6a_{n-1} $$
So
$$  a_{n+1}-6a_n  = 2(  a_n-6a_{n-1}   )$$

$$ \implies  a_{n+1} -8a_n + 12 a_{n-1} = 0 $$
So if $a_n$ has the form $a_n = bx^n$ we have ...
$$x^2 - 8x + 12 = 0 $$
So $x$ can be either $2$ or $6$

Try a solution of the form ...
$$  a_n = b (2^n) + c (6^n) $$
plugging this into $2^n = a_{n+1}-6a_n$...
$$2^n = b(2^{n+1})  +  c(6^{n+1})-6\bigg(    b(2^{n})  +  c(6^{n}) \bigg )$$
So
$$ (1+4b)2^n = 0 $$
So we must have $b=-\frac 14$ and $c$ can be anything

So
$$ a_n = -2^{n-2} + c(6^n)  $$
Solves the recurrence for any value of $c$.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a recurrence of second order write :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
a_{n + 2} & = & 6 a_{n + 1} + 2^{n + 1} \\[3mm]
a_{n + 1} & = & 6 a_n + 2^n
\end{array}\right.$$
then multiplying the second equation by $2$ :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
a_{n + 2} & = & 6 a_{n + 1} + 2^{n + 1} \\[3mm]
2 a_{n + 1} & = & 12 a_n + 2^{n + 1}
\end{array}\right.$$
we deduce by substracting :
$$a_{n + 2} - 2 a_{n + 1} = 6 a_{n + 1} - 12 a_n$$
Finally :
$$a_{n + 2} - 8 a_{n + 1} + 12 a_n = 0$$